# JAX-RS and @Produces ability to match on regex

Tags: jax-rs

I'm writing a Restful web service that requires  versioning. The way I want to go about this is using the Media type in the header to do this.

Example of request:

```
Accept: application/vnd.test.books.v1+xml
```

I would have an endpoint of

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces("application/vnd.test.books.v1+xml")
public Response getA(){
...
}
```

I would also like to have regex matching all versions. So I want to match on anything with Accept header of application/vnd.test.books.*+xml . So any version in my case. I tried something like the following with no lucks.

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces("application/vnd.test.books*+xml")
public Response getB(){
...
}
```

What I want is the ability to down the line have endpoint for v1 specifically then anything above v2 I want a different end point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must explicitly list all the MIME types a method `@Produces`:

```
@Produces(value = {"application/vnd.test.books.v2+xml",
                   "application/vnd.test.books.v3+xml",
                   "application/vnd.test.books.v4+xml"})
```